# Locate the last row of a group in a foreach for writing out an HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having a problem in my asp.net (c#) code, getting my foreach loop to do a specific thing when it reaches a new row input from my database; a quick example:

I have my database throwing out 5 set of rows:

```
       column
row1 | ca     
row2 | ca
row3 | ro
row4 | ro
row5 | ef
```

These rows I put into a foreach loop, and loop 'em into an HTML table. This way I want a `border-bottom`, just before each time it gets into a new "set" of row. I want it all to be dynamic, if possible.

I want my table to look this way when it gets output:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>ca</td></tr>
 <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid Red'><td>ca</td></tr>
 <tr><td>ro</td></tr>
 <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid Red'><td>ro</td></tr>
 <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid Red'><td>ef</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would just like to add that I'm fairly new to the whole c#-world and programming in general, but I'm learning and love it :) - I hope you guys can help me out.. And just say if anything isn't clear enough and I will try to elaborate.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
 //HERE I WANT MY TR TO HAVE A BORDER BOTTOM WHEN IT REACHES A NEW SET OF ROW
 if (row["colLink"].ToString() != "") {
  litTilbud.Text += "<tr onClick='window.open(\"" + row["colLink"] + "\", \"_blank\")' style='cursor: pointer;'>";
 } else {
  litTilbud.Text += "<tr>";
 }
 litTilbud.Text +=  "<td class='tooltip' title='" + row["colDok"] + " - Tilføjet af: " + row["colNavn"] + "'>" + row["colSodavand"] + "</td>";
 litTilbud.Text +=  "<td>" + row["colAntal"] + " " + row["colType"] + " a " + row["colStorrelse"] + "L</td>";
 litTilbud.Text +=  "<td><strong>" + string.Format("{0:#.00}", row["colPris"]) + ",-</strong></td>";
 litTilbud.Text +=  "<td>(" + string.Format("{0:#.00}", row["Literpris"]) + ",-)</td>";
 litTilbud.Text +=  "<td>" + row["colSupermarked"] + "</td>";
 litTilbud.Text += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: "Displays the values of a data source in a table where each column represents a field and each row represents a record. The GridView control enables you to select, sort, and edit these items." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

Comment: Can you put the code you have tried, if any, in your question please.

Comment: Please show the code, and give details about the problem you are encountering.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your specific problem is

Comment: you really need to provide some sample code - what technologies are you using (ASP.Net constitutes a complex family), what objects, etc?

Comment: Is your problem that your trying to display data on an ASP.NET page or that you want to display new data differently (if so how do you know that new data has been found)?

Comment: Ah, you added some code. Since you're learning C#/ASP.NET: it's usually best not to write literal HTML in your code-behind. Instead, use any of the many already available server side controls (here: GridView is a good choice, but others may apply as well). Doing it the way you do, you loose a lot of compile time checking, and it is _very_ hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a foreach loop. Instead, try to use a `Repeater`, or a `GridView`. Then all you need to do is bind your data (your database output) and you're done.

I suggest looking up some samples on how to use this. It's a bit of learning, but it gives you more control and makes your code easier to understand.

A simplified example, edit it to suit your needs:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" CssClass="MyGridStyle"
    OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_OnRowDataBound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="yourDataField" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In your code behind, you place an eventhandler, like so:

```
protected void MyGrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // only datarows, no header rows:
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // user e.Row.DataItem to get to the data
        if(your logic here about groups)
        {
             e.Row.Style = "border-bottom:solid black 1px";
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `Page_Load` you can add the following code to bind the GridView with your data:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = YourObjectWithDataFromDatabase;
MyGrid.DataBind();   // bind data to gridview
```

Note: if your datasource has exactly the fields that your want, no more, no less, you can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`, and remove the `Columns`-definition, this makes your code even easier.

Comment: Alright, as said in my mainpost my I'm in a learning phase right now.. But I sure will look into GridView and see if that will ease up my problem or do it any easier to understand, thanks :)

Comment: The "your logic here about groups" is the critical piece of the puzzle IMO.  Arguably that's going to be harder using a GridView than building it by hand where you have access to all the rows at once.

Comment: @tvanfosson that depends. In each event you still have access to all the data. If the datatype he uses has a property that can be read, it's trivial this way. If grouping and/or sorting still needs to be done, it's better done before the collection is assigned. But it's a guessing game, the OP hasn't left enough clues to find out.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier if you can iterate using an index rather than `foreach`.  Assuming that your collection can be accessed via an index (a reasonably safe assumption, I think).  It might look like:

```
 for (int i =0; i < collection.Count - 1; ++i)
 {
      var row = // create a new row
      string current = collection[i];
      string next = collection[i+1];
      if (current != next)
      {
           // add a "lastitem" class or set the style directly
      }
 }
 if (collection.Count > 0)
 {
     // build the last row with "lastitem" class (or setting style directly)
 }
```

You'll note that I glossed over building the row since you haven't specified if you're using WebForms and are building the row as text (not a particular good idea) or as HTML elements (better), or are using ASP.NET MVC and building the row in your view directly (best option, IMO).

Also, I think you'd be better off using a CSS class such as `lastitem' rather than setting the styles on the elements directly.  Your code will be much cleaner for it and if you ever decide to display things differently all you will need to do is change your CSS file rather than rewrite your code.

```
.lastitem {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a column to your dataset with a flag that specifies if you need to do decorations in html.
Then all you need is to write a loop.
It will look smth like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
sb.Append("<table>");
foreach(var row in rowsCollection) 
{
   if(row.NeedsDecoration) 
   {
       sb.Append(" <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid Red'><td>");
   } else sb.Append("<tr><td>");

   sb.Append(row.YourField);
   sb.Append("</td></tr>");
}
sb.Append("</table>");

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That mixes data and representation, generally not something you should do. Instead, this logic should go in the representation or business layer. However, you can augment your data objects with an extension method, NeedsDecoration(), in which case you would still have this separation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you started with ADO.NET and retrieving the data from your database and storing it in a `DataTable`.  This is untested code, but you'll get the general flow of logic.

```
public void GetDataAndDisplay()
{
    DataTable myData = new DataTable();
    myData = GetDataFromDb();
    LoopThroughTable(myData);
}

public DataTable GetDataFromDb()
{
    // you can also stored your connection string in the web.config file
    //  and utilize ConfigurationManager class
    SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection("your connectionstring here");
    SqlCommand GetData = new SqlCommand();
    GetData.Connection = dbConn;
    GetData.CommandText = "select col1, col2 from yourTable";

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(GetData);
    DataTable YourData = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        dataAdapter.Fill(YourData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }

    return YourData;
}

public void LoopThroughTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        // construct your html strings here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, the best thing to do would be to make use of a 3rd party control (or even one of the asp.net built-in controls) that allows you to let it deal with this for you. That said, the best way I can think of to do this would be to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ).

### The example

If you create a new WebForm page and paste the following into it (in the codebehind, the `.aspx.cs` file) (**I do explain what all this does a bit further down**):

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    var result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add("ColumnToGroupBy", typeof(string));
    result.Columns.Add("AnotherColumn", typeof(int));
    result.Columns.Add("YetAnotherColumn", typeof(string));

    result.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ca", 3, "abc" });
    result.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ca", 4, "cake" });
    result.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ro", 8, "apple" });
    result.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ro", 1, "pair" });
    result.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ef", 2, "okra" });

    return result;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = GetData();

    var groupedData = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                        group row by row.Field<string>("ColumnToGroupBy") into grouping
                        select grouping;

    foreach (var group in groupedData)
    {
        TableRow row = null;
        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = item.Field<string>("ColumnToGroupBy") });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = item.Field<string>("YetAnotherColumn") });
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        row.CssClass = "CssClassThatSetsTheBottomBorder";
    }

}
```

Then put the following in the main markup (the `.aspx` file), replacing the equivalent that markup that Visual Studio has created for you:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .CssClassThatSetsTheBottomBorder
        {
            /* I've used a background colour as it's more obvious */
            background-color: Red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="myTable">

    </asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### The explanation

The first block of the example basically has a method called "GetData" which is there to pretend to be your databae. The interesting thing happens in the second part:

```
var groupedData = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("ColumnToGroupBy") into grouping
                    select grouping;
```

What this does is takes all the rows of data that you have and puts them into **groups**, based on the value in the `ColumnToGroupBy` column, so we have a group for `ca`, a group for `ro` and a group for `ef`. The code then takes each group in turn and writes each of the rows out to the table (I've used the asp.net WebForms built-in Table/TableRow/TableCell, rather than writing the HTML myself). Because we're looping over each group and then each item in each group, once we've done the last item in the group we can set its Css Style to have a bottom border. That's what the `row.CssClass = "CssClassThatSetsTheBottomBorder";` line does.

Try the code out, have a play around with it and it should hopefully make sense =)

Comment: That is more like it. I'm getting my data from my mssql database.. I'm trying out the code you wrote.. I need to apply css styles and such to the tr aswell.. ?

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen, yup - I've shown you how to do it with a CSS Class, rather than styles - it's easier to do it that way with the built in controls plus it gives you a better separation between your HTML markup and your styling. For example, if you wanted to change the way it looks later, you just change your stylesheet without having to edit your code, or even give the stylesheet to a designer to work on without them having to touch your code =)